# Python Дубликаты

Tags: python

Есть .txt файл `File.txt`. B нём находится текст с дубликатами.

Kак их удалить?
Думаю, через `replace`, но не знаю как правильно реализовать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286860/removing-duplicates-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: `''.join(sorted(set(string),key=string.index))`

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(sorted(set(string),key=string.index))
```